# How to keep a text inside a div when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css

So I have a simple div in which I have a p with some text. I want the text to stay inside the div, and that is going good so far, but when I resize the window of my browser horizontal, the text inside the div is flowing out of the div on the bottom.

```css
#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  top: 420px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox">
  <p id="text">Here is some example text that is about the same amount as I really have here, but I don't want to reveal what.</p>
</div>
```

According to the answers on similar questions, I have to add `word-wrap: break-word;` which I already have.
If this helps, the text is not flowing out at left or right, it flows out at the bottom.

So my question, what do I do, to keep the text inside the div when I'm moving the browser window?

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: normal;`?

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:hidden;` on `#textbox`?

Comment: @Barrosy yes I did. It doesn't work.

Comment: @yip102011 yes I did, but this hides and I'm looking for a different solution.

Comment: @Gyrgam you cannot give your box 1 fixed and 1 responsive dimension if you do not want the text not to come out of it - either make them both fixed, or make them both fluid (eg remove the height if you are going to have a responsive width)

Comment: Please remove height from the div `<div id="textbox>"` element. Height will automatically be set to the content of the element this way. Default value for height would be automatic.

Comment: @Pete Oh, didn't knew that. And that was what I was doing wrong. Thank you, but because I'm new here I don't know how to set a comment as a solution..

Comment: @Gyrgam you cannot mark a comment as an answer :)  I would mark the min-height one below - pretty much the same thing

Comment: @Pete yeah, that works too. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `height: 250px` to `min-height: 250px;`

```css
#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  top: 420px;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox">
  <p id="text">Here is some example text that is about the same amount as I really have here, but I don't want to reveal what.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are remove height if you will use

 left: calc(50% - 10%);
      top: calc(50% - 125px);

Comment: I only changed the height to min height, the rest of the code is the op's code. You'll have to ask him...

Comment: if you will write left : calc(50% - 10%) and top: calc(50% - 125px then it willbe not working without change any height)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `top` and `left` only help positioning the element. They won't change the height. Again, you can comment under the question and ask the person who asked the question wht he decided to position his element this way.

Answer (score 1):

you can keep text inside by simply change you style.

online demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y5sjdtoq/

try this style code:

```
    #textbox {
        left: 180px;
        top: 420px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 240px;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    #text {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 20px;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: That is a nice solution and I appreciate it but I prefer the already accepted one.